# Does an AJAX call on the Admin Side Automatically include the User Data/Capabilities?

Tags: users, ajax, capabilities

I was wondering that if you do an AJAX call on an admin page and I wanted to see if the user had the capability to edit a page, would that info be sent along the call or do I need to manually sent that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send any additional data, since the user cookies (which are used for authentication) will be sent by default.

You have access to all the WP functions, including current_user_can().